# How to introduce noise into sequence data using TraMineR?

Tags: r, sequence-analysis, traminer

I want to randomly change states in a sequence dataset for the purposes of simulation. The goal is to see how different measures of cluster quality behave with different degrees of structure in the data.

If I were to introduce missings, there is the handy `seqgen.missing()` function in TraMineRextras, but it only adds missing states. How would I go about randomly picking a proportion `p`of sequences and randomly inserting a randomly selected element of the alphabet to them with `p_g`, `p_l`, and `p_r` probabilities for inserting them in the middle, left, and right?

Comment: This is a question about coding without statistical content. It should be asked on StackOverflow. In any case, you should explain to what you would like to change the randomly selected elements in the sequences. To a fixed state? A randomly selected element of the alphabet?

Comment: Ok. I understand. Please for free to vote for migrating it to the correct site. I’ll edit to clarify the points you raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a `seq.rand.chg` function (adapted from `seqgen.missing`) that randomly applies state changes to a proportion `p.cases` of sequences. For each randomly selected sequence the function randomly changes the state either

1. When `p.gaps > 0`, at a proportion between `0` and `p.gaps` of the positions;
2. When `p.left > 0` and/or `p.right > 0`, at an at most `p.left` (`p.right`) proportion  left (right) positions.

As in the `seqgen.missing` function, the `p.gaps`, `p.left`, and `p.right` are the maximum proportion of cases changed in each selected sequence. These are not exactly your probabilities `p_g`, `p_l`, and `p_r`. But it should be easy to adapt the function for that.

Here is the function:

```
seq.rand.chg <- function(seqdata, p.cases=.1, p.left=.0, p.gaps=0.1, p.right=.0){
  n <- nrow(seqdata)
  alph <- alphabet(seqdata)
  lalph <- length(alph)
  lgth <- max(seqlength(seqdata))

  nm <- round(p.cases * n, 0)
  ## selecting cases
  idm <- sort(sample(1:n, nm))
  rdu.r <- runif(n,min=0,max=p.right)
  rdu.g <- runif(n,min=0,max=p.gaps)
  rdu.l <- runif(n,min=0,max=p.left)

  for (i in idm){
    # inner positions
    gaps <- sample(1:lgth, round(rdu.g[i] * lgth, 0))
    seqdata[i,gaps] <- alph[sample(1:lalph, length(gaps), replace=TRUE)]
    # left positions
    nl <- round(rdu.l[i] * lgth, 0)
    if (nl>0) seqdata[i,1:nl] <- alph[sample(1:lalph, nl, replace=TRUE)]
    # right positions
    nr <- round(rdu.r[i] * lgth, 0)
    if (nr>0) seqdata[i,(lgth-nr+1):lgth] <- alph[sample(1:lalph, nr, replace=TRUE)]
  }

  return(seqdata)
}
```

We illustrate the usage of the function with the first three sequences of the `mvad` data

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
mvad.lab <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education",
              "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.shortlab <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:62], states = mvad.shortlab,
                   labels = mvad.lab, xtstep = 6)
mvad.ori <- mvad.seq[1:3,]

## Changing up to 50% of states in 30% of the sequences
seed=11
mvad.chg <- seq.rand.chg(mvad.ori, p.cases = .3, p.gaps=0.5)

## plotting the outcome 
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
seqiplot(mvad.ori, with.legend=FALSE, main="Original sequences")
seqiplot(mvad.chg, with.legend=FALSE, main="After random changes")
seqlegend(mvad.ori, ncol=6 )
```

[image: Sequences before and after changes]]

We observe that changes were applied to the randomly selected 3rd sequence.